# Shared Array with more complicated element type

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

A simplified example:

```
nsize = 100
vsize = 10000
varray = [rand(vsize) for i in 1:nsize] #say, I have a set of vectors.

for k in 1:nsize
    varray[k] = rand(vsize, vsize) * varray[k]
end
```

Obviously, the above for loop can be parallelized.

According to [Parallel Map and Loops](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing/#parallel-map-and-loops) in Julia manual, 
I need to used `SharedArray`. However, `ShardArray` cannot have `Array{Float64,1}` as element type.

```
julia> a = SharedArray(Array{Float64,1}, nsize)
ERROR: ArgumentError: type of SharedArray elements must be bits types, got Array{Float64,1}
 in __SharedArray#138__ at sharedarray.jl:45
 in SharedArray at sharedarray.jl:116
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, you can't, because a `SharedArray` requires a contiguous block of memory, which means that its elements must be "bits types," and this isn't true for `Array`. (`Array` is implemented in C and has some header information, which makes them not densely-packable.)

However, if all of your "element" arrays have the same size, and you don't absolutely require the ability to modify single elements of the "inner" arrays, you could try using `StaticArrays` as elements. (Thanks to @Wouter in the comments below for pointing out that this needed updating.)

Comment: A quick update if someone still has this problem in 2021: use StaticArrays

Comment: Thanks Wouter, I edited the above and credited you.